# Clear nuxt store and all submodules at logout

Tags: vue.js, vuex, nuxt.js

I'm wondering what's the best solution to reset all my store once a user logout.
Typically I have an app where I log in and sometimes in dev mode I need to switch from account (which can be the case in live mode). And obviously I've some issues when I log with another user, some store infos are still there and belongs to other user (dunno if I'm clear). 
I already clear some module from my store inside my logout function inside auth.js. But as my app is growing, and store (decoupling in several modules) also, I just wonder what's the best approach to reset all my store at once, with initial value/state.

Any thoughts ?

Comment: https://vuex.vuejs.org/api/#replacestate

Comment: and here for modules https://forum.vuejs.org/t/how-to-completely-reset-the-vuex-store/13611

Answer (score 1):

This is how I'm clearing out some data from the store in Nuxt.

```
clearToken(state) {
   state.token = null
   state.refresh = null
   state.currentUserData = null
},

logout(vuexContext, req) {
    vuexContext.commit('clearToken')
    Cookie.remove('jwt')
    Cookie.remove('jwt_refresh')
    Cookie.remove("tokenExpiration");
    Cookie.remove("userData");
    if (process.client) {
      localStorage.removeItem('refresh');
      localStorage.removeItem('token');
      localStorage.removeItem("tokenExpiration");
      localStorage.removeItem("userData");
    if (!localStorage.getItem('token')) {
      $nuxt.$router.push('/login/');
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can clean all vuex data using: `localStorage.vuex = ''`